# running error with console.log(util.format

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

First I have to say, I'm new to node.js.

One of my mate helped me with the piece of code below.

I've installed the required packages `search-google-geocode` , `csv-parser` , `fs` , `util` and `async` through `npm`.

Yet, when I'm running it.

I've got this error

```
console.log(util.format("  Area %s", preciseLoc.area);
                ^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:906:3
```

I thought first it was due to a missing semi-colon but it is not the case.

Does it sound familiar? If yes, do you have any ideas on how to fix the issue?

**The piece of code**

```
var geocoder = require('search-google-geocode');
var csv = require('csv-parser');
var fs = require('fs');
var util = require('util');
var async = require('async');

var options = {
    language: 'fr'
};

var locs = [];

var csvReader = fs.createReadStream('locs2.csv').pipe(csv());

var geoResult = function(err, result) {
}

csvReader.on('data', function(data) {
    locs.push(data);
});

var rowCount = 1;
csvReader.on('end', function() {
    console.log(locs.length + " rows read from CSV");
    async.eachSeries(locs, function(loc, cb) {
        console.log("\nLooking up row " + rowCount + ": " + loc.lat + "," + loc.lon);
        rowCount++;
        geocoder.reverseGeocode(loc.lat, loc.lon, function(err, result) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                var preciseLoc = result[0];
                console.log(util.format("Reverse geocode: %s, %s", preciseLoc.latitude, preciseLoc.longitude)
                console.log(util.format("  Area %s", preciseLoc.area));
                console.log(util.format("  Zip %s", preciseLoc.zipcode));
            }

            cb();
        } , options);
    },

    function(err) {
        return null;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like this line:

```
console.log(util.format("Reverse geocode: %s, %s", preciseLoc.latitude, preciseLoc.longitude)
```

is missing a closing bracket and should probably be changed to:

```
console.log(util.format("Reverse geocode: %s, %s", preciseLoc.latitude, preciseLoc.longitude));
```

Comment: Damn. Thanks Ben. It was that -_-